# Addition of extract value from the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition

I extracted value from the title as you can see. But I have problem with the addition. Basically I dont know how to add every .work-day-graph element in .ct-chart. So it will be like 1,25+8,25+0,75+0,5 = XY and 2,25+7,25+2,75+0,5 =XY. Any ideas ? Thanks a lot

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/1xn1eLfs/6/

JS:

```
$('.ct-chart').each(function() {
 var graphTitle;

 $(this).find('.work-day-graph').each(function() {
    graphTitle = $(this).attr('title');
    var graphTime = graphTitle.substring(graphTitle.lastIndexOf('(') + 1, graphTitle.lastIndexOf('h'));
    //graphTimeVal = graphTime.parseInt();

    $('<span class=output-val>' + graphTime + '</br>' + '</span>').appendTo('.output');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3woe2cdq/4/

If you want to display the sum for both charts, you need a separate output inside both of them to make it work.

```
$('.ct-chart').each(function() {
  var graphTitle;

  // Save the sum of the hours
  var graphTimeSum = 0;

  $(this).find('.work-day-graph').each(function() {
    graphTitle = $(this).attr('title');

    var graphTime = graphTitle
      .substring(graphTitle
        .lastIndexOf('(') + 1, graphTitle
        .lastIndexOf('h')
      ).replace(',', '.');

    // Add the current hours to the sum
    graphTimeSum += parseFloat(graphTime);
  });

  // Here we select the output class inside the chart
  $('<span class=output-val>' + graphTimeSum + '</br>' + '</span>').appendTo($(this).find('.output'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be carefull because you use "," and not "." in your string. To add those number, you must parseFloat on them.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/1xn1eLfs/6/

```
 var val = 0;
$('.ct-chart').each(function() {
    var graphTitle;

    $(this).find('.work-day-graph').each(function() {
        graphTitle = $(this).attr('title');
        var graphTime = graphTitle.substring(graphTitle.lastIndexOf('(') + 1, graphTitle.lastIndexOf('h'));
        graphTime = graphTime.replace(',', '.');
        val += parseFloat(graphTime);

        $('<span class=output-val>' + graphTime + '</br>' + '</span>').appendTo('.output');
    });
});
console.log(val); // 23.5
```

Do the same but changing the second ct-chart class by ct-chart2 or whatever, so you can add element independently.